# Trying to convert an entire structure to a string in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, structure

I'm using a structure as follows:

```
Structure USERREC
    Public UserRecID As Integer
    Public CompanyRecID As Integer
    Public Username As String
    Public LoggedInTime As DateTime
    Public UserIsLocked As Boolean
    Public UserFirstName As String
    Public UserLastName As String
    Public UserEmail As String
    ... deleted for simplicity ...
End Structure
```

When I instantiate this type into a variable `(Dim ThisUserRec As USERREC = (data routine) )`, I can break the code and go to the immediate window and simply type `"? ThisUserRec"` and I see a nice display of every element in the structure

```
? ThisuserRec
{USERREC}
    UserFirstName: "Alex                                                        "
    UserIsDeleted: False
    UserIsLocked: False
    UserIsOwnerMgr: False
```

I removed elements for security and simplicity purposes in this example.

So, I'd love to save the entire structure into my audit table as a string.  I was hoping there was some easy way like

```
Dim ThisUserRecString as String = ThisUserRec
```

but of course, I know that won't work.

Anybody know a quick way to dump  the contents of a structure into a string?  Or an HTML table?

Comment: Take a look at this and see if it helps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

What you're looking for is some kind of serialization, and this is for JSON serialization which is very light and easy-to-read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easely serialize to JSon with [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx).

This guy has a great example: [How can I make DataContractJsonSerializer serialize an object as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178255/how-can-i-make-datacontractjsonserializer-serialize-an-object-as-a-string)

I converted it to VB

```
Private Function ToJson(Of T)(data As T) As String
    Dim serializer As New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(T))

    Using ms As New MemoryStream()
        serializer.WriteObject(ms, data)
        Return Encoding.[Default].GetString(ms.ToArray())
    End Using
End Function
```

Just call it like this

```
ToJson(Of USERREC)(object)
```

Don't forget to import the libraries

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
```

And make it serializable

```
<Serializable()> _
```

Comment: That's excellent, thanks.  It may be sloppy, but the info is there and that's what I needed.  Sadly I don't have enough of a reputation to vote.

Comment: @Ron Great! You should be able to check it as answer