# C# How to deserialize json object to string

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a json object to a string coming from a webservices but I cannot make it.
I have tried to put [IgnoreDataMember] attribute but it sets it to null.

I'm going this :

```
DataContractJsonSerializer MySerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response));
Response response = (Response)MySerializer.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(e.Result)));
```

Here is my Response class :

```
public class Reponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public data1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<AnotherData> data2 { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherData
{
      [DataMember]
       public string name { get; set; }

       public object object1 {get; set;}

}
```

I would like to get deserialize my JSON object called object1 as a string not as an object. How can I do that ?

Thanks for helping

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178255/how-can-i-make-datacontractjsonserializer-serialize-an-object-as-a-string

Comment: This is a good example for serializing. But i want to deserialize.

Comment: What does the JSON look like?  In the JSON does `"object1"` just have a string value, or is its value some nested JSON object or array?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom behaviour with a custom dispatcher inheriting from IDispatchMessageFormatter. Please take this [exemple](http://itq.nl/replacing-wcf-datacontractjsonserializer-with-newtonsoft-jsonserializer/) and update it.

In the DeserializeRequest method, you'll read the message :

```
var bodyReader = message.GetReaderAtBodyContents();
        bodyReader.ReadStartElement("Binary");
        byte[] rawBody = bodyReader.ReadContentAsBase64();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(rawBody);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
        string content = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```